# Django's JSON and XML fixtures cause UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode, django-models

I created a JSON file using Django's `dumpdata` command. When I import the data again with `syncdb`, Python throws an exception:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 231: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This must be related to the JSON file (and not my models.py), because the problem does not occur with `--no-initial-data`. Now I wonder where my encodings get mixed up.

The JSON file contains strings like `'Garc\u00eda Ram\u00f3n'`. When I encode the actual string with Python manually with either UTF-8 or Latin1, I get:

```
>>> ustring = u'García Ramón'
>>> ustring.encode('utf-8')
'Garc\xc3\xada Ram\xc3\xb3n'
>>> ustring.encode('latin1')
'Garc\xeda Ram\xf3n'
```

Why does syncdb choke on dumpdata's output? And what could I do to prevent this? Both the source and the target DB (MySQL and PostgreSQL, respectively) use UTF-8.

**Update:** The exact same thing happens when using XML as the serialization format, with proper encoding declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<django-objects version="1.0">
[...]
<field type="CharField" name="last_name">García Ramón</field>
```

I have no idea at what point Django tries to encode `ü` (= `u'\xfc'`) using the ascii codec (and how I could change that). I tracked the issue back to line 185 in `xml_serializer.py`:

```
 self.xml = SimplerXMLGenerator(self.stream, self.options.get("encoding", settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET))
```

and added `DEFAULT_CHARSET='utf-8'` to `settings.py`, but now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

did you put

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

to the top of your .py files?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This answer also doesn't have anything to do with the question asked. You do not need to put this line in your file to work with unicode data in the user input or data files (unless you use Unicode characters directly in your code, but the question is clearly not about that)